# Error importing imblearn in Jupyter and from commandline

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, importerror, imblearn

I tried to import SMOTE from imblearn this way:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
```

I'm using Jupyter Notebooks but because I have Windows I cannot use the terminal that came with Jupyter.
I have anaconda so on the anaconda prompt I wrote:

```
"pip install imblearn"
```

Afterwards, I upgraded sklearn (because I've got an error of that):

```
"pip install --upgrade sklearn"
```

The upgrade and the install ran well in Anaconda prompt.

But then I've got another error on my notebook:

```
"ImportError: cannot import name '_LearntSelectorMixin'"
```

Which, I think, is an element from sklearn that couldn't be imported

I don't know if i'm doing something wrong... or what I can do.
Thanks!

Comment: Im having the exact same problem after upgrading sklearn and installing imblearn